# how to make Form2 visible no matter what the state of Form1 (main form ) is?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

using Delphi XE (1) i have a application with TWO forms

Form1 is the main form..

Form2 is a msn like notification (a form that slide to show notification then disappears ).

stuff working smoothly until the form1 is minimized.

Q: how i make form2 show visible even if form1(main) is minimized to taskbar

Comment: I guess that form1 is your mainform, so miminizing it means minimize the application. There is no way around it I think. Unless form2 is made the mainform and it creates form1 but than you cannot close form2 without closing the application

Comment: I would look up how to do Toast Notifications in delphi, sounds close to what you're looking for.

Comment: form2 is not actually closed its located at < frmNotify.Left := Screen.Width ; >   its start sliding when needed

Comment: @Guido That's not true at all

Comment: Make the second form be an unowned tool window in win32 terms

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I stand corrected In my defense I did say "I think"...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i can't use tool window  because it will show a window frame with a close button and that does not look nice for that purpose.

Comment: You can get rid of that I believe. I suggested tool window to avoid being on the task bar. Otherwise you will have to make it be owned by an I visible window other than your main window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CreateParams to override default behavior. Something like this:

Add declaration to your form

```
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
```

Add a procedure

```
procedure TMyForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);

  with Params do
  begin
    Style := WS_POPUP or WS_BORDER;
    ExStyle := WS_EX_TOPMOST or WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
    WndParent := 0;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Don't ever make the desktop be your window's owner

Comment: Right, it should be 0 (I was too hurry).